# Matplotlib and Seaborn display issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

How should i do to show the axes value(dataframe's columns name) vertically?
following is my code, it will display the columns' name horizontally as fig shows.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns

adress='D:\\data\\ltl_credit_model_30.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(adress,sep=',')
corr=df.corr()

#Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 20))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 100,as_cmap=True)

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=1,linewidths=.5,
        cbar_kws={"shrink": .6},annot=True,annot_kws={"size":8} )
plt.show()
```

Resulting figure:
[image: Graph]

Comment: yes .thanks for your kindly help